# Converting C program into 32-bit assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am stuck with converting *C* code into assembly. Here is the code that I need to convert:

```
#include <stdio.h>
define N 50 int x[N], y[N], z[2 * N];
void convolve(int[], int[], int[], int);

int main(void)
{
    int i, n;
    printf("Enter vector size (<=%d): ", N);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter first vector (%d elements):\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        **scanf("%d", &x[i]);
    **printf("Enter second vector (%d elements):\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &y[i]);
    convolve(x, y, z, n);
    printf("Convolution:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ((n + n) - 1); i++)
        printf("%d ", z[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void convolve(int x[], int y[], int z[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ((n + n) - 1); i++)
        z[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            z[i + j] += x[i] * y[j];
    return;
}
```

I am stuck at this line:

```
scanf("%d", &x[i]);
```

How do I insert into array?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    .data
    .align 4

state: .long 0

    .bss
    N = 50
    int x[N], y[N], z[2*N]

    .data
    .equ N, 50
    .comm i,4,4      #int b
    .comm n,4,4      #int n
    .comm j,4,4      #int j
    .comm x,N*4,4    #int x[N] where N is 50
    .comm y,N*4,4    #int x[N] where N is 50
    .comm z,N*8,4    #int x[N] where N is 100

    .section .rodata    #to format strings

fmt0:  .string "Enter vector size (<=%d): "
fmt1:  .string "%d"
fmt2:  .string "Enter first element (%d elements):\n"
fmt3:  .string "Enter second element (%d elements):\n"
fmt4:  .string "Convolution:\n"
fmt5:  .string "\n"
fmt6:  .string .%d .

    .text
    .globl main

main:
    pushl  %ebp               #prolog
    movl   %esp, %ebp

    pushl  %esi               #save callee-save registers %esi, %edi, and %ebx onto stack
    pushl  %edi               # where  %esi at -4(%ebp),%edi at -8(%ebp), and %ebx at -12(%ebp)
    pushl  %ebx
    pushl  %eax               #for array where %eax at -16(%ebp)------------------------------

    /* Allocate space for i and n on the stack */
    subl $8, %esp
    /* i is at address -20(%ebp) */
    /* n is at address -24(%ebp) */

    pushl  $fmt0           #push fmt0
    call   printf          #printf("Enter vector size (<=%d): ")
    addl   $4, %esp        #deallocate parm to printf

    leal   -24(%ebp), %ebx #%ebx = address of n
    pushl  %ebx            #push address of n
    pushl  $fmt1           #push fmt1 "%d"
    call   scanf           #scanf ("%d", &n)
    addl   $8, %esp        #dealoccate parms for scanf

    pushl  $fmt2           #push fmt2
    call   printf          #printf("Enter first element (%d elements):\n")
    addl   $4, %esp        #deallocate parm to printf

    movl   $0, -20(%ebp)   #i=0
    movl   -20(%ebp), %edi #%edi=i
    movl   -24(%ebp), %esi #esi=n
    cmpl   %esi, %edi      #compare i:n
    jg     for_done        #jump to for_done if i>n

for_loop:
     pushl   %edi           #push i
     pushl   %esi           #push n
     pushl   %eax           #push array

     pushl   $fmt1          #push fmt1 ("%d")
     call    scanf          #scanf("%d", n)
     addl    $8, %esp   #dealocate parms to scanf
     movl   (address of x,%edi,4), %eax------------------------------------------------------

     incl   %edi            #%edi++ (i++)
     movl   %edi,-20(%ebp)  #i=%edi
     compl  %esi, %edi      #compare i:n
     jle    for_loop        #jump to for_loop if i<n

for_done:
     addl   $8, %esp        #deallocate local vars from stack
     popl   %ebx            #restore %ebx
     popl   %edi        #restore %edi
     popl   %esi        #restore %esi

/*next loop for second vector*/

     pushl  %esi               #save callee-save registers %esi, %edi, and %ebx onto stack
     pushl  %edi               # where  %esi at -4(%ebp),%edi at -8(%ebp), and %ebx at -12(%ebp)
     pushl  %ebx
     pushl  $fmt3           #push fmt3
     call   printf          #printf("Enter second element (%d elements):\n")
     addl   $4, %esp        #deallocate parm to printf

     movl   $0, -20(%ebp)   #i=0
     movl   -20(%ebp), %edi #%edi=i
     movl   -24(%ebp), %esi #esi=n
     cmpl   %esi, %edi      #compare i:n
     jg     for_done        #jump to for_done if i>n

for_loop:
     pushl   %edi           #push i
     pushl   %esi           #push n
     pushl   %eax           #push array
     pushl   $fmt1          #push fmt1 ("%d")
     call    scanf          #scanf("%d", n)
     addl    $8, %esp   #dealocate parms to scanf
     movl   (address of y,%edi,4), %eax------------------------------------------------------

     incl   %edi            #%edi++ (i++)
     movl   %edi,-20(%ebp)  #i=%edi
     compl  %esi, %edi      #compare i:n
     jle    for_loop        #jump to for_loop if i<n

for_done:
     addl   $8, %esp        #deallocate local vars from stack
     popl   %ebx            #restore %ebx
     popl   %edi        #restore %edi
     popl   %esi        #restore %esi

     leave      #epilog
     ret

convolve:

     pushl  %ebp               #prolog
     movl   %esp, %ebp
     pushl  %esi               #save callee-save registers %esi, %edi, and %ebx onto stack
     pushl  %edi               # where  %esi at -4(%ebp),%edi at -8(%ebp), and %ebx at -12(%ebp)
     pushl  %ebx
     /* Allocate space for x, y, z, n, i, and j on the stack */
     subl $24, %esp

     /* x is at address 4(%ebp) */
     /* y is at address 8(%ebp) */
     /* z is at address 12(%ebp) */
     /* n is at address 16(%ebp) */
     /* i is at address -16(%ebp) */
     /* n is at address -20(%ebp) */

    movl   $0, -16(%ebp)   #i=0
    movl   -16(%ebp), %edi #%edi=i
    movl   -20(%ebp), %esi #esi=n
    addl   %esi, %esi   #2 times n
    subl   $1, %esi     #2n - 1
    cmpl   %esi, %edi      #compare i:n
    jg     for_done        #jump to for_done if i>n
```

Comment: Hint: look at the `lea` instruction. You should of course pass the address of `x[i]` to scanf, and you should not push `i` or `n` since this invocation doesn't use those and will unbalance your stack.

Comment: You mean leal? Do I need to do this for array?:pushl  %eax

Comment: i am pushing address of array, correct?

Comment: Which instructions for ggc convertion from c code into assembly you would suggest? I am not trying to copy, I just get lost in the order that I need to do.

Comment: The line marked with the `---` should be `leal x(, %edi, 4), %eax` and move it up to before the `push %eax`.

Comment: Like for example, I am starting with main, where i do printf and scanf, then loop for first and second vector, when do I do this:  convolve(x, y, z, n); ? before my print statement printf("Convolution:\n"); .... ?

Comment: Hmmm. the line with -----, are you talking about in the loop? or the one that is almost right after main?

Comment: Inside the function, you should do things in the order they were in C, unless they can be safely reordered. The `printf` and the `convolve` can be swapped without any visible effect in program behavior. The order of the functions themselves don't matter.

Comment: This line `movl   (address of x,%edi,4), %eax` You need to do something similar for the other one too.

Comment: For which one, the other one?

Comment: TWO SUGGESTIONS: 1) compile your C program with `gcc -O0 -S ...` to see the GCC assembly code, 2) Check out Jonathan Bartlett's excellent book about Linux/Assembler: [Programming from the Ground Up](http://savannah.gnu.org/).

Comment: you mean for &y[i]? Do you save these in different register, correct?

Comment: I did compile it with gcc -O0 -S, but it is hard to understand, that's just not what I am learning in my class...:(

Comment: Yes, the `&y[i]`. You will need to push it as argument to `scanf`, doesn't matter which register.

Comment: Also, I have a question, when I do for example loop, can I clear the registers and use them again for next loop?

Comment: Yes, you can reuse registers as you wish, assuming you no longer need the previous value.

Comment: When I do this line: convolve(x, y, z, n); what do I need to do exactly?just assign the memory allocation, and address, and save the addresses into registers?

Comment: Them how do I pass the values of x, y, z, and n into void convolve function? as what exactly? after this leal x(, %edi, 4), %eax, do I call them as like %eax? or how to I assign each value of the element in the array into -4(%ebp), -8(%ebp). etc..

Comment: You don't pass each value to convolve, you pass the array addresses. Such as: `push n; push $z; push $y; push $x; call convolve; add $16, %esp`.

Comment: Got it, I am gonna try to implement all that! I really appreciate your help. Also, so far am I doing everything correct with my assembly code? Do you see any errors?

Comment: @paulsm4:`-O0` is pretty noisy and hard to read, since it stores and reloads all variables between expressions.  I think modern debug-info formats can tell debuggers when a variable is live in a register, because ` -Og` doesn't do that.  It means "optimize for debugging", and makes less noisy asm that still does pretty much what the source says.  It's easier to keep track of what's going on when you see the same register used for a few insns in a row, instead of having to notice that it's the same address.  `-fverbose-asm` is sometimes helpful, too.  Also see http://gcc.godbolt.org/.

Comment: gcc.godbolt.org - bad getaway, when you say fvetbose-asm is this for converting C into asm via gcc?

Comment: "-S" is for converting C into asm via gcc.  gcc.godbolt.org suggested that -fverbose-asm" can be a good switch to use in addition to "-S".  If assembly is new to you, I strongly urge you to read Bartlett's book.  It's available free, on-line via the link above.

Comment: how do I run .s file on Windows cmd line?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but notice you've got two different for_loop and for_done defined; you might want to differentiate them somehow.

as per some of the other suggestions, maybe something like this, for example, could work:

```
for_loop1:
     pushl   %edi           #push i
     pushl   %esi           #push n
     leal    x(,%edi,4), %eax
     pushl   %eax           #push array
```

...

```
for_loop2:
     pushl   %edi           #push i
     pushl   %esi           #push n
     leal    y(,%edi,4), %eax
     pushl   %eax           #push array
```